# Negative of elliptic curve points

Tags: elliptic-curves, cryptography

F<sub>8</sub> is defined as:

```
 0    000
 1    100
 β1   010
 β2   001
 β3   110
 β4   011
 β5   111
 β6   101
```

What type of elliptic curve model is meant by y<sup>2</sup> + xy = x<sup>3</sup> + β<sup>2</sup>x<sup>2</sup> + β<sup>6</sup>  over F<sub>8</sub>?

What are the negatives of the following points: P = (β<sup>3</sup>, β<sup>6</sup>),  Q = (0, β<sup>3</sup>),  R = (β, 0) ?

Comment: If $(x,y)$ is a solution to an elliptic curve, its inverse is $(x,-y)$.

Comment: But say (β3, β6) is a point on the elliptic curve (which it is), how do you find -β6?

Comment: By finding the additive inverse of $\beta_{6}$

Comment: It's only true for elliptic curves in Weierstrass form, in general, that the additive inverse of $(x,y)$ is $(x,-y)$. This equation is not in Weierstrass form, because of the $xy$ term. How have you defined the group law on this elliptic curve? [It's not uniquely defined.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve#The_group_law)

Comment: That's the problem I'm having. I'm not entirely sure of the laws behind the elliptic curve for this particular problem assigned. For an example, I know that the points P=(β^2,β^6) Q=(β^5,β^5) added together will yield R=(β^3,β^6). **λ** = (y1+y2)/(x1+x2) = β/(β^3) = (β) β^(-3) = β*β^4 = β^5.    Also x3 = λ^2 + λ + A + x1 + x2 = **β^3**    and y3 = λ(x1 + x3) + y1 + x3 = **β^6**

Comment: @GregMartin, this curve is in generalized W-form, where we may assume that the identity point is the point $\Bbb O$ at infinity. That being given, the law of combination will always be that $P+Q+R=\Bbb O$ if and only if $P$, $Q$, and $R$ are collinear.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old but it has not been properly answered.  Since this is not a Weierstrass equation but an elliptic curve equation defined over a finite field, negative points are found using the following rule:

- If $P = (x_P, y_P)$, then $P + (x_P,   x_P  +  y_P) = O$.
- $P + (x_P, x_P + y_P) = O$.

The point $(x_P, x_P + y_P)$ is the negative of $P$, which is denoted as $−P$.

My source: page 312, *Cryptography and Network Security: Principles and Practice*, 7th edition, by William Stallings, Prentice Hall

Comment: Hey @jpc0016, welcome to Math Stackexchange! Thanks for your answer, and although we support HTML editing, using LaTeX is the preferred way on this site. It looks much nicer too :) Here is a quick guide: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0):

This is generalized Weierstrass form, with the restriction that you have specified. There’s no name for it, far as I know. In all cases, you get the negative of a point $P$ in the finite plane by finding the other point with the same $x$-coordinate.